# Eclipse does not place jar from an included project specified in deployment assembly (but does for others)

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have three java projects that are being included in the main project. 2 out of the 3 projects are working just fine, a jar with all their classes automatically ends up in the WEB-INF/lib, but the third project's jar doesn't get export.

These exact projects were all working just fine in eclipse 3.6 (Springsource Toolsuite 2.5.5), but now with STS 2.7 and eclipse 3.7 (indigo), the third project's jar just never gets exported. If I manually export the jar to the running webapp, everything works normally as well.

Any ideas why this one project dependency is not getting a jar file exported to the parent app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the same error I was having, I may have a solution.

**Some more symptoms**:  You go to the main project, try to add the dependent module using the "Deployment Assembly" properties panel, click "OK" and when you come back, it's gone again! but the file .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component shows you added it.

Also, when you go to the dependent project's properties, and bring up the "Deployment Assemby", it's empty.  If you try to add a mapping /src -> / , it doesn't stick.

**If this is your problem, then try this:**

First, in your main project's .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component file, remove all the entries for your dependent project.  Then, in your dependent project, go under .settings.  You probably do not have a file called org.eclipse.wst.common.component , or if you do, it's content may be invalid.  Create/edit the file to contain something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
  <wb-module deploy-name="my-module">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src"/>
  </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Next, bring up the "Deployment Assembly" for the dependent module to make sure you get the /src -> / mapping, and add any other parts that need to be included in the jar.  Finally, bring up the "Deployment Assembly" for the main project and add your dependent project.

Good luck.

Comment: interestingly both the main project, and the project added as a dependency had the component file, and they were all set up correctly, except that the dependent project file was missing the "<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src"/>" line, adding that back in fixed it! no idea how that might have gotten erased, definitely nothing that was done manually-

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without detailed information about the configuration of the projects — but, is the JAR set to be exported?

Open the project properties *→ Java Build Path → Order and Export* and make sure the checkbox next to the problematic JAR is checked.

Comment: the checkbox is definitely checked, please let me know what configuration details I should add, I would love to figure this out, its so odd that other projects are being included just fine, but not this one (anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but it came from maven 3, who generated

```
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="2.0">
```

instead of

```
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
```

I just went back to maven 2

Answer (score 0):

I added the "Project" to the Deployment Assembly on the properties page (right-mouse button on the project name --> properties option  --> deployment assembly).

The problem occurs if the dependent project is open.  For some reason, the dependent project does not get included with the other maven dependencies.

If the dependent project is closed and there is a jar in the maven repository (mvn install), then it will be moved to the WEB-INF/lib directory with the other maven dependencies.